# Active Storage - Adding File Description / Text - Ruby on Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

With the release of Rails 5.2, the much used [Paperclip gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) is now deprecated and it's advised to use [Active Storage](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html) that ships with Rails. I'm starting a new project and set up Active Storage with ease, but my problem comes when trying to add a name or description to the file uploads.

With Paperclip I would add a column to the model called something like file_upload_name, so that as well as having a file name "something.pdf" I could also add a name or description such as "My Important Document" on the upload form.

For the projects that I'm doing, this is a vital part of the upload process and ideally needs to be done at the time of upload. As Active Record doesn't store to a model in such a way it's not as simple as just adding a column and adding fields to a form. It seems something that should be relatively simple but I can't figure it out or find any information about how best to do it. Any help much appreciated.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

With Active Storage the end result is a multiple file upload button, with no naming etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should create a new model to wrap each attached file.  That model would then have the ActiveStorage attachment defined on it, as well as whatever other attributes you need to capture.  Ex:

```
class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :file
end
```

Rails then treats `file` kind of like an attribute for each Attachment.  You can define your other attributes (e.g. upload_name, etc.) on the Attachment model.  Based on your screenshot, it looks like maybe a Quotation has many attached files, so you'd do something like:

```
class Quotation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attachments
end
```

Comment: What about the upload form ?